# Shortcut to change a line of words to a vertical list in Sublime Text 2

Tags: list, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts

[image]Is it possible to make this title on line 1 a list of items from each word or symbol seperated by a space with a keyboard shortcut. So that I can select the title and then hit a shortcut and it will make the title a list of items like below:

[image]

Tried saving the Key Binding file.

Comment: You should accept @skuroda's answer if it correctly answers your question.

Comment: No worries I will, we just haven't reached a solution yet. skuroda has been a huge help so far though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing built in, but you can do it with a plugin.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re


class SplitLineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, split_pattern=" "):
        view = self.view
        cursors = view.sel()
        if len(cursors) == 1:
            cursor = cursors[0]
            begin_offset = 0
            end_offset = 0
            if cursor.empty():
                region = view.line(cursor)
                content = view.substr(region)
                new_content = re.sub(split_pattern, "\n", content)

                view.replace(edit, region, new_content)
            else:
                region = cursor
                content = view.substr(region)
                new_content = ""
                if view.line(region).begin() != region.begin():
                    new_content = "\n"
                    begin_offset = 1
                new_content += re.sub(split_pattern, "\n", content)

                if view.line(region).end() != region.end():
                    new_content += "\n"
                    end_offset = - 1

            view.replace(edit, region, new_content)
            cursors.clear()
            cursors.add(sublime.Region(region.begin() + begin_offset, region.begin() + len(new_content) + end_offset))
            view.run_command("split_selection_into_lines")
```

You can then add the following in your key binding file.

```
[
    { "keys": ["f8"], "command": "split_line", "args": {"split_pattern": " "}}
]
```

Of course changing the key to something that you want. You don't actually need the `args` argument if you are just using a space. It defaults to that. I just included it for completeness.

**Edit:**
I've updated the plugin so it now handles selections, though it does not handle multiple cursors at this point.

**Edit 2**
If it is not working, try opening the console and entering `view.run_command("split_line")`. This will run the command in whatever view you were in prior to switching to the console. This way you know if the command actually works. If it doesn't then there is a problem with the plugin. If it does, then there is a problem with the key binding.

Comment: Where do I save the new plugin to?

Comment: The easiest way to create the plugin is to go to `Tools -> New Plugin...` Copy and paste this code (it should work, but if you run into issues, please comment). Then save the file. You will want to save it in the `Packages/User` directory. It should default to there when you try to save the plugin file. Save the file as `<something>.py` replacing `<something>` with a name that is meaningful to you. After that, simply add the key binding to your user key bindings file.

Comment: Ok did all that, I guess I'm only confused about the last part now. Do I have to save the key binding when I put it in the user key binding file? What do I save it as? See new photo above for what I experienced when I tried to save it. (note: I didn't save anything cause I didn't want to mess anything up)

Comment: Open the user keybinding file by going to `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`. The key binding configuration is JSON. The key bindings specifically are an array containing object entries. You don't want to overwrite what is already there, but rather extend it. What I listed would be an entry in that array.

Comment: My key bindings in "User" doesn't have anything in it yet, is that ok? "Defualt" on the other hand has a ton! By the way I really appreciate your consistant help on this matter :)

Comment: Yes it's fine. The key binding files are merged together. I've updated the sample to show what it should look like in your user key binding file (assuming no previous entries as you indicated)..

Comment: Got it. After I paste it do I exit that tab or do I have to save it?

Comment: Save first. Well' it will probably prompt you to save anyways since you made changes to the file :)

Comment: Ok I did that, It’s not working, all I have to do is select a sentence and hit [F8] and it should work theoretically right?

Comment: It looks for an empty region right now (no selection just have the cursor on the line).

Comment: Open the console (`View -> Show Console`) and enter `sublime.log_commands(True)`. Then press F8. What appears in the console?

Comment: command: drag_select {"event": {"button": 1, "x": 351.5, "y": 126.5}}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27996/discussion-between-skuroda-and-seth-urquhart)

Comment: Thanks for this @skuroda. One issue may have been the arg is different in the key binding. It works if you change split_str to split_pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the above code for my own use, so that it now respects whitespace. But I hard-coded tabs instead of spaces, so if you use spaces you might have to change it further. It also now assumes you have no text selected and instead have the cursor in the middle of the line to be changed to vertical spacing. I left intro/outro as arguments so you can also use it for [] or (), although maybe some more escaping is needed in that case for the regex.

Before:

```lua
        fields = { 'Team1', 'Team2', 'Player1', 'Player2', 'Tab=Round', 'DateTime_UTC=DateTime', 'HasTime=TimeEntered', 'OverviewPage=Tournament', 'ShownName', 'Winner', 'Stream' },
```

After:

```lua
        fields = {
            'Team1',
            'Team2',
            'Player1',
            'Player2',
            'Tab=Round',
            'DateTime_UTC=DateTime',
            'HasTime=TimeEntered',
            'OverviewPage=Tournament',
            'ShownName',
            'Winner',
            'Stream',
        },
```

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import re

class SplitLineCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, sep=",", repl= "\n", intro="{", outro="}"):
        view = self.view
        find = re.escape(sep + ' ') + '*(?! *$| *\n)'
        intro_repl = intro + repl
        intro = intro + ' *'
        outro_repl_start = sep + repl
        outro_repl_end = outro
        outro = ',? *' + outro
        repl = sep + repl
        cursors = view.sel()
        if len(cursors) == 1:
            cursor = cursors[0]
            begin_offset = 0
            end_offset = 0
            if cursor.empty():
                region = view.line(cursor)
                content = view.substr(region)
                line_str = view.substr(view.line(view.sel()[0]))
                tabs = len(line_str) - len(line_str.lstrip())
                intro_repl = intro_repl + '\t' * (tabs + 1)
                repl = repl + '\t' * (tabs + 1)
                outro_repl = outro_repl_start + ('\t' * tabs) + outro_repl_end
                content = re.sub(outro, outro_repl, content)
                content = re.sub(find, repl, content)
                content = re.sub(intro, intro_repl, content)
                view.replace(edit, region, content)
            cursors.clear()
            cursors.add(sublime.Region(region.begin() + begin_offset, region.begin() + len(content) + end_offset))
            view.run_command("split_selection_into_lines")
```