# Adding Custom Menus in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

How to add a custom Menu item in **SublimeText 2** .

Any Ideas ??
I see there is a **Main.sublime-menu** file but dont know how to edit it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The *.sublime-menu file is simply JSON. You can create a Main.sublime-menu in your user directory and it will be merged with other menu entries. It may be beneficial to look through the Main.sublime-menu files third party plugins have. These are generally much shorter, so may be easier to understand some of the things you need to define in each entry.

**edit**

You can use the following as a plugin to open notepad with an arbitrary file.

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
import subprocess
import threading
class OpenNotepadCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, filename=None):
        th = NotepadThread(filename)
        th.start()

class NotepadThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        self.filename = filename
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        if self.filename is not None:
            subprocess.call("notepad.exe %s" % self.filename)
        else:
            subprocess.call("notepad.exe")
```

When you are creating a menu item use something like the following for the command and arguments.

```
{
    "command": "open_notepad",
    "args": { "filename": "<the absolute path here>"}
}
```

Comment: The `default` packages directory contains the built-in official main (menubar) and contextual (right-click) menus.  I believe it is also possible to customize the sidebar menu -- see sidebar enhancements plugin . . .

Comment: @skuroda Searching Google. Cant find anything useful.  Does anybody know how to create a plugin that can run a file from Sublime Text.  I will manage my way from that.  Thanks

Comment: @AviAryan What are you trying to run? Plugins are simply python so you can use the subprocess module to create new processes and execute whatever you want. You may also want to take a look at [Build Systems](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) or [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL).

Comment: @skuroda  I'm trying to run something  like -- `notepad.exe "<filepath>"`          And I dont know python , hope you understand that. If you can provide me a simple plugin that does the above, that would be lovely.

Comment: I've added something very quick to open a file with notepad. For details on how to install a plugin, see the comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838945/shortcut-to-change-a-line-of-words-to-a-vertical-list-sublime-text-2/15841316#15841316

Comment: Frogot to mention @AviAryan

Comment: @skuroda Excellent, it just works! I also added it to a menu and created a keyboard shortcut . Thanks !!

Answer (score 14):

Easier option if what you want is just run a command. Create a file Context.sublime-menu inside your Packages/User directory, and add the following:

```
[
    { "caption": "<Your caption here>", "command": "exec", "args": {"cmd": ["<your cmd name>", "<arg1>", "<arg2>", <...>]} }
]
```

Exemple: Adding a menu item to the context menu that just run dir:

```
[
   { "caption": "List files in current dir", "command": "exec", "args": {"cmd": ["dir"]} }
]
```

Comment: This answer helped me greatly, since there is so much out there on this topic that doesn't really cover this simple operation.

Comment: However, to get it to work on my Windows ST2, I had to add this as one of the elements (a sibling to caption and command, etc)...
"id": "justSomethingUniqueLikeActionName"

So here's my code to run a sequence for the RegReplace Plugin...
`{
 "id": "cfmlToCfScript",
 "caption": "CFML to CfScript",
 "command": "reg_replace",
 "args": {
  "replacements": [
   "operation1"
   , "operation2"
  ]
  , "find_only": false
 }
}`

Comment: If you have made a directory for the plugin (ie. `Packages/plugin_name`) put the sublime-menu file in that directory and use the plugin's command name in the `command` value of the JSON. E.g:
`{ "caption": "Plugin desc", "command": "plugin_cmd"}`

Answer (score 4):

I know this way too late to join the party and add my 2 cents. Anyway, Main.sublime-menu is a file that allows you to add menu items to the top menu i.e [File, Edit, Selection, Find, View, Goto, etc.]

I recently added a new section "Dev" just to figure it out.  I also wanted a way to trigger browser previews for a specific browser.  Check it out.

```
  [
    {
    "caption": "Dev",
    "mnemonic": "Z",
    "id": "dev",
    "children": [
      {
        "caption" : "Previews",
        "children": [
          { "caption": "Markdown Live Preview", "command": "new_markdown_live_preview", "id": "markdown_live_preview" },
          { "caption": "Preview in Default Browser", "command": "view_in_browser", "id": "markdown_live_preview" },
          { "caption": "Preview in Firefox", "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "firefox" }, "id": "markdown_live_preview" },
          { "caption": "Preview in Chrome","command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "chrome" }, "id": "markdown_live_preview" },
          { "caption": "Preview in Safari", "command": "view_in_browser", "args": { "browser": "safari" }, "id": "markdown_live_preview" },
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Anyway, this still works in ST3.  Just in case anyone stumbles around here.

Comment: These websites provide extra help. https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/menus.html https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/menus.html