# Sublime Text disable goto animation

Tags: sublimetext, text-editor

When using the goto function to bring my cursor to a particular line number, say **3017**, how do I prevent Sublime from jumping around from line to line **until I hit enter**?

For instance, in that case, I would jump to the following lines:

- 3
- 30
- 301
- 3017 (finally)

Answer (score 4):

Sublime Text 3 seems to have two "Goto Line" features:

1. one which is built in via the "Goto Anything" overlay. Internally, the command to execute this is `show_overlay` with the arguments `{"overlay": "goto", "text": ":"}`.  This is the default, available from the Goto menu -> Goto Line, and with keybinding Ctrl+G. [MattDMo is correct in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981062/4473405) that it is not possible to disable fuzzy matching in this overlay.
2. one which is included in the "Default" package as a plugin and shows a small prompt panel at the bottom of the screen.  Internally, the command to execute this is `prompt_goto_line`, with no arguments necessary. This implementation has the behavior you desire, and will only go to the specified line when you hit the enter key.  It has no default way of accessing it, but read on... :)

The reason I have mentioned the internal commands above is because Sublime Text makes it possible to [add or override keybindings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html), and also to [change or add menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147073/adding-custom-menus-in-sublime-text), and the commands are used to instruct Sublime Text what action to perform.
Therefore, this means that you can choose to override the existing menu item and/or keybinding, (and/or you can create a new menu item and/or keybinding) to use the `prompt_goto_line` command. The two links I have just provided should give enough detail on how to perform these tasks, but if you would like more specific information, please let me know in a comment and I will provide it.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. The short answer is to add:   { "keys": ["ctrl+g"], "command": "prompt_goto_line"}, to your keybindings file.

Comment: @Keith Hall , When hide the overlay dialog(goto or something like that), the focus will auto jump back to the previous position. That's annoying. Will you supply a configure to disable the "auto jump back" behavior? Thanks!

Comment: @Pickmeup101 You can just create a keybinding like `{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "select", "context":
        [
            { "key": "overlay_has_focus", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
        ],
    },`

Answer (score 2):

This feature is by design, and cannot be disabled. Most popup menus in Sublime feature "fuzzy matching", meaning you do not need to type the full search term, just a few letters (for example, ***`pci`*** finds `Package Control: Install Package` in the Command Palette). The menus also feature instant searching, which is what you are seeing. This means that you do not need to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to search, just start typing and the matches appear as you type.