# How to place multi cursor every char/word in selection

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying to place a multiple cursor after every character in my selection? I am also trying to place a multiple cursor after every word in my selection. Is this possible?

Thanks I'm a new user to sublime and am thinking of making the move from notepad++

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to split a word by chars in ST2, but to see this answer [for some ideas on how to place a cursor at each word in a selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838945/shortcut-to-change-a-line-of-words-to-a-vertical-list-in-sublime-text-2/15841316#15841316).